# prove that $q_n = p_n \, \sin(\frac{t}{2^{n-1}})$ is a geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, geometric-progressions

Given
$$p_n = \prod_{n}^{p=1} \cos\left(\frac{t}{2^{n-1}}\right) \hspace{3mm} \text{and} \hspace{3mm} q_n = p_n \, \sin\left(\frac{t}{2^{n-1}}\right).$$ 
How to prove that $(q_n)_{n}$ is a geometric progression with $\frac{1}{2}$ as ratio ?

Comment: is it me or are you indices backwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sin a=2\cos\frac a2\sin\frac a2=4\cos\frac a2\cos\frac a4\sin\frac a4=8\cos\frac a2\cos\frac a4\cos\frac a8\sin\frac a8=\cdots$$

Comment: useful , $q_{n+1} = \prod_{p=1}^{n}cos(\frac{t}{2^{p-1}})cos(\frac{t}{2^{n}})sin(\frac{t}{2^{n}})
 $ and next $ q_{n+1} = \prod_{p=1}^{n}cos(\frac{t}{2^{p-1}}) \frac{1}{2} sin(\frac{t}{2^{n}}) $

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Compute the Quotient $$\frac{q_{n+1}}{q_n}=\frac{p_{n+1}\sin\left(\frac{t}{2^n}\right)}{p_n\sin\left(\frac{t}{2^{n-1}}\right)}$$